# Any way to interpret a command without running cmd.exe?

Tags: shell, cmd, windows-shell

I am looking for a way to run an executable or a script without getting cmd.exe to do it for me. Currently I'm launching a process using `cmd.exe /C <command>`, which I need to do the following things for me:

- Look for the executable file in the current directory and PATH
- Interpret PATHEXT to permit extension-less script commands
- Interpret file associations to, e.g., run the python interpreter when I tell it to run `blah.py`.

I *don't* need to be able to run any of the "built-in" commands, like "dir".

Is it possible to avoid using `cmd.exe` without essentially re-implementing all of the above functionality? There must be some sort of shell API to do the above things, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShellExecute should do exactly what you want - you can use it to launch an executable or a file (which is then opened with the standard application),

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: At a glance, it doesn't appear to resolve PATH or PATHEXT - is that so, or does it actually do that?

Comment: It does (which might be a security risk), see https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding/825-BSI.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( appName, args) .
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx and about the shell, have you looked it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773177(v=vs.85).aspx ?